# How to insert rows into table using cursor in Firebird?

Tags: cursor, firebird, firebird2.5

Collegues, I am new in Firebird. I'am trying to call procedure (`p_procedure`) in cursor cycle and insert result into table (`tmp_port`).

```sql
execute block
as
declare contr integer;
declare IN$DT date;
declare cur_list_of_cont cursor for (select first 100 contracts.doc from TABLE_1);

begin

delete from  tmp_port;
IN$DT = getdate()-2;

open cur_list_of_cont;
  while (ROW_COUNT > 0) do
  begin
    fetch cur_list_of_cont into contr;


     insert into tmp_port (
        DT,
        ....)

        select
            :IN$DT as DT,
            ...
        from p_procedure (0,  :contr , :IN$DT);


    if (ROW_COUNT = 0) then leave;
    suspend;
  end
  close cur_list_of_cont;

end;
```

The problem is that only single, fisrt row processed from cur_list_of_cont. 
Why other 99 rows are not processed?

**UPDATE**

FireBird Server version is `2.5`

**UPDATE**

In this realization it works fine:

```
begin

IN$DT = getdate()-2;

FOR select first 100 contracts.doc from TABLE_1
 INTO :contr 
 DO
  BEGIN
  insert into tmp_port (
        DT,
        ....)

        select
            :IN$DT as DT,
            ...
        from p_procedure (0,  :contr , :IN$DT);

  END
  SUSPEND;

end;
```

It will be better if the first example works too. How to do it?

Comment: Have you checked that `p_procedure` returns record(s) for each record from the cursor? IOW if the `p_procedure` returns empty resultset for the second row, nothing would be inserted into tmp_port, thus ROW_COUNT would be zero and loop would be broken...

Comment: @ain thank you for ypur idea. Cursor `cur_list_of_cont` returns two  contracts.doc (1999 and 2000). I call  `p_procedure` with these two contracts.doc and it returns results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `ROW_COUNT` incorrectly. As documented in the [Firebird 2.5 language reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-row_count):

> *Description*: The `ROW_COUNT` context variable contains the number of rows affected by the most recent DML statement (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT` or `FETCH`) in the current trigger, stored procedure or executable block.
>
> ...
>
> - After a `FETCH` from a cursor, `ROW_COUNT` is 1 if a data row was retrieved and 0 otherwise. Fetching more records from the same cursor does not increment `ROW_COUNT` beyond 1.

The `while (ROW_COUNT > 0)` might be false if nothing was deleted, you might also exit the loop if your procedure returns no rows and therefor nothing was inserted.

If you look at the [example of using `FETCH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-fetch), you can modify your code to:

```sql
open cur_list_of_cont;
fetch cur_list_of_cont into contr;
while (row_count > 0) do
begin
    insert into tmp_port (
          DT,
          ....)
      select
          :IN$DT as DT,
          ...
      from p_procedure (0,  :contr , :IN$DT);
    fetch cur_list_of_cont into contr;
end
close cur_list_of_cont;
```

However, given your code, you should consider using `FOR SELECT` as it is easier in most cases.

Comment: thank you. It works. I used to work in Oracle with `open...fetch` construction and tried to use it in Firebird. Could you explain why `for select` construction is more preferred?

Comment: @May12 As long as you don't need to do multiple fetches inside the loop body, or other more tricky things, I would prefer simplicity over complexity. And in my opinion, for select is just simpler as you don't need to use explicit cursor operations like fetch, and handle the looping.